# [RAILS]: Listing Results by address using ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, ransack

I'm new on Ror,
I need some help to display my products on my index page.
I'm using ransack gem, to filter my active results, but I don't succeed to filter them nearby a geocoded address if it is typed in the form..?
Each product has an address.
Thks for your help!

Here is my code:
products/index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <label>Type d'article:</label><br>
  <%= f.label :name_cont, 'article:' %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_cont %>

  <%= f.label :brand_cont, 'marque:' %>
  <%= f.search_field :brand_cont %>

  <%= f.label :size_cont, 'taille:' %>
  <%= f.search_field :size_cont %>

  <label>Prix:</label><br>
  <%= f.label :price_gteq, 'prix min:' %>
  <%= f.number_field :price_gteq %>

  <%= f.label :price_lteq, 'prix max:' %>
  <%= f.number_field :price_lteq %>

  <label>Adresse:</label>
  <%= f.text_field :address, placeholder: "Où est situé votre article ?", id:"user_input_autocomplete_address", class: "form-control" %>
  <input id="street_number" name="street_number" disabled type="hidden">
  <input id="route" name="route" disabled type="hidden">
  <input id="locality" name="locality" disabled type="hidden">
  <input id="country" name="country" disabled type="hidden">

<%= f.submit 'Lancer la recherche', class:'btn btn-info btn-sm' %>                   
<% end %>
...
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_JAVASCRIPT_KEY']}"></script>
```

Products controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_product, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
   before_action :authenticate_user!, except: %i[show index slide]

def index
    @search = Product.ransack(params[:q])
    @products = @search.result.where(active: true).near(@address, 50)
  end

private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :brand, :category, :color, :size, :state, :price, :address, :status, :active)
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you have a go at fixing the indentation please? It will make it a lot easier for people to help.

Comment: ok thk you, but my problem is not solved :-(

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/geocoder-display-maps-and-find-places-in-rails/) Samy - seems to cover what you're looking to do. If you want them to update as a form is filled, you'll need to use Javascript and AJAX to update the results and it will be a fairly complex problem (probably too large for someone to answer here). Hopefully the link helps get you there - if you run into any problems on the way, by all means create another question relating to specific issues :)